# Wpf Resize object with window

Tags: wpf, resize

Looked around to find a way to resize bind with the windows resize without explicitly telling my object to grab the windows size.

Here is the code:

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <WindowsFormsHost Background="{x:Null}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="windowsFormsHost1" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="-1,0,0,0">
        <wf:Panel x:Name="pnlLivePreview" />
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

This was followed by the example showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495947/how-to-make-textbox-resize-as-the-window-resize/4496009#4496009)

Edit: Question: Why doesn't panel resize with the window ?

Comment: @Aviad - aww, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer: Problem is not the panel but the api used to create the content of it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the explicit `Width` and `Height` settings, and the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` settings, thus:

```
<WindowsFormsHost Background="{x:Null}" 
                  Name="windowsFormsHost1" 
                  Margin="-1,0,0,0">
    <wf:Panel x:Name="pnlLivePreview" />
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

I'm going to throw a wild guess here, but since this is a `WinForms` panel, try setting it's `Dock` property to `Fill` thus:

```
    <wf:Panel x:Name="pnlLivePreview" Dock="Fill" />
```

Really not sure it would work, if it doesn't work in markup, try doing it in code.

Comment: You could also remove the `Grid` entirely if there's nothing else going in there.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that, the problem with that is: it just resizes on load, not while the window is resizing.

Comment: My guess is that the `WindowsFormsHost` itself does resize with the window, but the `wf:Panel` inside it does not since it doesn't follow the WPF layout rules.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much, looked it up on msdn and it's a window form component. tried adding a autosize=true to it and yet no avail.

Comment: BTW I just tested it without the dock part, and the panel does actually resize with the window, I don't know what the problem is with your markup.

Comment: I think, I figured it out. The class I send a ref of the panel to, changes the setting for panel... gotta re change afterwards I suppose.

Comment: @Aviad - Yea, it's the api I am working with.... +1 for all the help and new knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Bind your Height/Width to your window's height/width

```
<Window x:Name="Root_Window">
  <Grid Height="{Binding ElementName=RootWindow, Path=ActualHeight}"
        Width="{Binding ElementName=RootWindow, Path=ActualWidth}">
      <!-- Content Here -->
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: pretty new at wpf, how would u do that ?

Comment: That would not resize the panel inside the grid, which is what I'm actually trying to resize

Comment: @Reza M. The panel inside the Grid will automatically expand to fill all available space

Comment: Does it work if you set the Height/Width binding on your WindowsFormsHost?

Comment: Rachel, all you said do work,.. im positive it is the panel itself missing up everything.

Comment: @Rachel - Yea, it's the api I am working with.... +1 for all the help and new knowledge